# How to send an email from one user to another, locally and offline?

Tags: linux, command-line, email, hostname, mailutils

I'm just testing a [few things](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494144/847449) with e-mail and want to send something with `mailutils` strictly locally and offline from one user to another:

```
tbird@mordor:~$ 
tbird@mordor:~$ mail nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
Cc: 
Subject: ping
anyone there?
 
.
..
 
 

(Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)
 
tbird@mordor:~$
```

Isn't there some special character to indicate EOF or end of the e-mail somehow?  I thought it was the single or double dot, but can't find the answer through Google or the man pages.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701317/108618

Answer (score 0):

it's `ctrl-d` to send:

```
tbird@mordor:~$ 
tbird@mordor:~$ mail
"/var/mail/tbird": 1 message 1 new
>N   1 nicholas           Mon Nov 27 15:48  15/555   ping
? 1
Return-Path: <nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
X-Original-To: tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
Delivered-To: tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
Received: by mordor.saundersconsulting.tech (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 15CC0378; Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:48:46 -0800 (PST)
To: <tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
Subject: ping
User-Agent: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.14)
Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:48:45 -0800
Message-Id: <20231127234846.15CC0378@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
From: nicholas <nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>

how to end


? q
Saved 1 message in /home/tbird/mbox
Held 0 messages in /var/mail/tbird
tbird@mordor:~$
```

not sure where I found that.

Comment: `not sure where I found that` that applies to many programs ... `ctrl-d` means `end of data` in nix